# Resolving "Quota N2_CPUS exceeded"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

From the [GCP quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas), I can increase the `CPUS` quota:

[image: CPUS quota]

As well as the `CPUS_ALL_REGIONS` quota:

[image: CPUS_ALL_REGIONS quota]

But whenever I try to increase an instance type-specific quota (e.g. `N2_CPUS`):

[image: N2_CPUS quota increase request]

[image: N2_CPUS quota increase confirmation]

I get an email confirmation from GCP Support saying the request was approved for `CPUS_ALL_REGIONS` instead of the expected `N2_CPUS`. After waiting a few moments, the quotas page still shows the default limits:

[image]

Which is confirmed when trying to launch a new VM instance with any amount of CPU larger than 8. I get error messages such as:

> Quota 'N2_CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 8.0 in region us-central1.

I've been trying for a few days, with no luck. There are no other VM instances in this project. Any thoughts?

Comment: If it’s normal project (not a free tier) I’d suggest to create a support ticket or open a private issue on issuetracker.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience you may need to contact Sales as your Quota Increase Request seems very large (64 x N2_CPUS).

Lets remember that quotas (either allocatable quotas or rate) are intended to  control and protect  the resources usage globally or in specific regions/zones.

Usually  a validation / revision of your business case is required in order to proceed with your specific request and not in a general way as it happened with the first quota increase request that was given to you in Global and not where you wanted.

Sometimes, depending on your request (resource type, and quantity ), this process should be done though a sales representative.

To reach out to Sales Team for assistance you  can visit this URL:
https://cloud.google.com/contact

Comment: Alright, I will do that. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!